# Insert a url inside a cell in fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

Suppose I have a link (example: www.example.com) and I want to insert the link as "Click Here" inside a cell in FPDF. My sample code is given below:

```
$pdf->Cell(70,12,'Download Link',1);                                        
$pdf->Cell(70,12,'',1);
$link="www.example.com"
$pdf->Write(12,'Click Here',$link);
```

I want the **'Click Here'** Option appear inside the second cell. But it's appearing beside the cell. How can I make it appear inside the cell?

Comment: Try ```$pdf->SetY(y_coordinate_here);``` before write

Comment: Try this `$pdf->Cell(45,12,'Click Here','1','0','C',false, $link);`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `Link` function in pdf, reference: http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/link.htm.

```
$pdf->Link(70,12,10,10, 'http://www.example.com');
```

OR with `Cell` reference: http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/cell.htm

```
$pdf->Cell(70,12,'Download Link', '','','',false, "http://www.example.com");
```